# Is there a mistake in the Upgrading CivCRM for WordPress instructions?

Tags: upgrade

I was following the instructions to upgrade to 4.7.14 here:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress
It clearly says to extract the zip file in  /wp-content/plugins/. It then says to clear caches and point to the upgrade url.
This leads to:
Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.13.
The extract left things in a directory called: civicrm-4.7.14-wordpress. This implied to me that the upgrade will move things from there to the civicrm directory, but reading things here and elsewhere I suspect that files need to be extracted (or moved) to the civicrm directory.  There are no instructions to do that. Should I remove the civicrm/ tree and move civicrm-4.7.14-wordpress/civicrm to plugins/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that was made in the instructions is that you must extract the files into the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory and then *rename* the resulting file to `civicrm`, just like the old directory was named. The previous step to this was to backup `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm`.

E.g. Back up and delete `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm` then extract the new version and name it `civicrm` and put it in `/wp-content/plugins/`, thus replace the previous.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Assumptions in instructions is not a good thing. Is there someone I should contact about correcting the instructions or should I just try to edit them myself?

Comment: I see now that my problem was that the gui tool I was using created an extra subdirectory to extract the zip file... so this was actually operator error.